# Using DATE_ADD with a Column Name as the Interval Value

Tags: mysql, sql, dateadd

I have a table which contains products, a start date and an interval value :

```
product_name                    start_date              expiry_period
Domain Registration (1 Year)    2013-12-08 00:00:00     1 Year
Domain Registration (1 Year)    2013-12-01 00:00:00     1 Year
Website Hosting (Bronze)        2013-12-19 00:00:00     1 Year
Website Hosting (Silver)        2013-12-20 00:00:00     1 Year
Website Hosting (Silver)        2013-12-21 00:00:00     1 Year
Domain Registration (2 years)   2014-01-04 00:00:00     2 Year
Domain Registration (1 Year)    2014-01-04 00:00:00     1 Year
Website Hosting (Silver)        2014-01-06 00:00:00     1 Year
Domain Registration (2 years)   2014-01-06 00:00:00     2 Year
Domain Registration (1 Year)    2014-01-07 00:00:00     1 Year
Domain Registration (1 Year)    2014-01-10 00:00:00     1 Year
Website Hosting (Bronze)        2014-01-12 00:00:00     1 Year
```

I'm trying to add a calculated value in my select statement to add the interval to the start_date so that my dataset returns with the start and end date programmatically.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
select 
    product_name, 
    start_date,
    expiry_period
    DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL expiry_period) as end_date
from
    tbl_products
```

However, it's returning an error against the DATE_ADD line (incorrect SQL Syntax).

All of the SO articles that I've read seem to indicate that the expression and the type need to be separate (i.e. `DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL expiry_value expiry_type)`) - Surely this isn't the case and I can just pass a period in one single field?

If not and since I can't change the data schema, what would be the recommended way of doing it? I contemplated using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to split the column by  but this doesn't appear to work either.

Comment: Will your interval qualifier always be `Year`?

Comment: No, it could be anything - Day/Week/Month/Year. Its just that my sample set of data above all said "Year"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It won't be easy o get your result - since you're storing it as plain `1 Year` or similar. It is **not** allowed to use it dynamically in `INTERVAL` construct - MySQL syntax [demands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) that you'll point both interval quantity and type.

However, there's kind of trick to resolve the matter:

```
SELECT 
    product_name, 
    start_date,
    expiry_period,
    @num:=CAST(expiry_period AS UNSIGNED),
    @p  :=SUBSTR(expiry_period, CHAR_LENGTH(@num)+2),
    CASE
      WHEN @p='Year' THEN DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL @num YEAR)
      WHEN @p='Month' THEN DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL @num MONTH)
      WHEN @p='Day' THEN DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL @num DAY)
      WHEN @p='Week' THEN DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL @num WEEK)
    END AS end_date
FROM
    tbl_products
```

-as you can see, this query relies on fact, that quantity always goes first (so [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) will extract exactly it, therefore, it can be used to get interval length after this). But in any case, you'll have to recount *all possible* interval types in [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) clause

Another good idea would be - to store your period in unified form (for example, always in days) - so you'll store only one number for each row (thus, 1 week=7days, e t.c.)

Comment: This is perfect - However, CHAR_LENGTH NEEDS to be +2 to account for the space in the Field Value. I tried to edit the answer, but it wont let me as it's less than 6 characters to change.

Answer (score 6):

You need to test for each one individually:

```
select product_name, start_date, expiry_period,
       (case when expiry_period like '%day'
             then DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL expiry_period + 0 DAY) as end_date
             when expiry_period like '%week'
             then DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL expiry_period + 0 WEEK) as end_date
             when expiry_period like '%month'
             then DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL expiry_period + 0 MONTH) as end_date
             when expiry_period like '%year'
             then DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL expiry_period + 0 YEAR) as end_date
       end)
from tbl_products;
```

The arithmetic (`+ 0` and `* 7`) converts the string to a number.