# SubstringIndex::$value undefined property - can't use in DATEADD

Tags: mysql, doctrine

The following query works

```sql
SELECT
   DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 1, 'DAY')
FROM table;

/* */
SELECT
   DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ' ', 1), 'DAY')
FROM table;
```

However, this one not:

```
SELECT
   DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ' ', -1))
FROM table;
```

`Column` property contains 1 MONTH which should be passed to DATE_ADD to modify the date, but the third argument of `DATE_ADD` `SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ' ', -1)` throws the following error in Doctrine:

`Notice: Undefined property: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\SubstringIndex::$value`

The code above is plain SQL so here's how I have it in Doctrine:

```php
->andWhere("createdAt > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ' ', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ' ', -1))")
```

Does it mean it cannot be written like this?

Comment: 1) In MySQL `DATE_ADD()` cannot have 3 arguments; 2) The unit in INTERVAL definition is not a data but a keyword, and won't be evaluated.

Comment: ok, I suppose I should use CASE WHEN to get this working like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403945/using-date-add-with-a-column-name-as-the-interval-value